# Jenkins triggering TFS plug in force Error TF400367

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I am triggering a build from Jenkins and the source code is in TFS2017 Update.3.1 using the TFS plugin to integrate.

When I trigger the build, it gives the error message below about the tfs connection.

Edit: [This solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2015-update3-vs) does not work for me.

> The build is in the workspace C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\tfp 中 FATAL:
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: The server could
>   not process the request。 ---> **TF400367: This request cannot be
>   executed because the host type does not match.Check all connection
>   information and verify that it is correct.The request is for
>   Deployment and Organization**。
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.SOAPFault: The server
>   could not process the request。 ---> ***TF400367: This request cannot
>   be executed because the host type does not match.Check all connection
>   information and verify that it is correct.The request is for
>   Deployment and Organization。***   at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAP12Service.examineResponseDOMForFault(SOAP12Service.java:117)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.examineBodyForFault(SOAPService.java:987)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:665)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:444)
>     at
>   ms.tfs.services.registration._03._RegistrationSoap12Service.getRegistrationEntries(_RegistrationSoap12Service.java:106)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:58)
>   Caused: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: The server
>   could not process the request。 ---> TF400367:  This request cannot be
>   executed because the host type does not match.Check all connection
>   information and verify that it is correct.The request is for
>   Deployment and Organization。  at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:92)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.RegistrationExceptionMapper.map(RegistrationExceptionMapper.java:18)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:61)

This is config screen capture:

[image]

Comment: Which version of TFS plugin do you use? There is an know issue on previous release https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33092, please try the latest release ....

Comment: thanks for reply，The plugin is latest version 5.142.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems the connection information you set is incorrect. You need to provide the collection name in the `Collection  URL`.

So, the Collection URL should be something like:  `http://192.168.101.188:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`